# Delete groups in Microsoft Graph API in C#

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I get an authorization `401` error code when I try to delete a Group from the API in C# but if I try it in postman it succeeds. Feels kinda weird because I run the same command but it doesn't work...

The problem I think I have is that to DELETE a group in Office 365 I need to login to my account and that the application can't makes this action.

I gave all `Group.ReadWrite.All` access and all other permissions for the application. So I think I need to pass my Login credentials for Azure AD or am I incorrect.

```
Request : 
   StatusCode: 401, 
   ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', 
   Version: 1.1, 
   Content: System.Net.Http.NoWriteNoSeekStreamContent, 
   Headers:
```

**EDIT**

I tried to not use my `GetAccessToken()` and use the token I got when using OAUTH 2.0 verification in Postman. If I took that bearer token I had no problem running my script and using DELETE.

So my question what the difference of using ADAL in C# code and the call that Postman Auth2.0. When using Postman I get a login page where I login to my Azure account, can I replicate this in code? For the authentication in C# I use [this example](https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/01/31/using-microsoft-graph-api-to-interact-with-azure-ad/).

**NEW EDIT**

As one wrote in the chat, I checked the access token and what roles I had on a website.

```
roles: [
  "EduRoster.Read.All",
  "Mail.ReadWrite",
  "User.ReadWrite.All",
  "Calendars.Read",
  "People.Read.All",
  "Group.Read.All",
  "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
  "MailboxSettings.Read",
  "Contacts.ReadWrite",
  "Group.ReadWrite.All",
  "Notes.Read.All",
  "Directory.Read.All",
  "User.Read.All",
  "Mail.Read",
  "Calendars.ReadWrite",
  "Mail.Send",
  "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite",
  "Contacts.Read",
  "Member.Read.Hidden",
  "Notes.ReadWrite.All"]
```

Comment: What is detail error message of the error . and could you please provide codes to help reproduce the error

Comment: Added some more information but nobody has run into this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Some clarification**:  If you have a token and it doesn't have the necessary claims/permissions to make the API call you are trying, you'll should get a 403 Forbidden.  If the token is missing in the API request or malformed, you'll get a 401 Unauthorized.  Please see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/errors.

Are you making direct HTTP REST calls to Graph, or are you using the client library?  I suggest that you look at some of our samples to get started for examples of token acquisition together with calls to Microsoft Graph. Try https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-csharp-snippets-sample (uses a .Net client library) or https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-rest-sample (uses direct HTTP REST calls).

Also are you acquiring a token in the context of a (signed-in) user, or in the context of the application (no signed in user)?  If the former, you need to request a "delegated" permission.  If the latter, you need to request an "application" permission. Please see these concepts:  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user and https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hello Dan, For the github repos, I looked at them and got the content and where you did the authentication. But the authentication seems much more advanced than when you use secret id and object id. 
I feel that I don't get whats done in the code example completely. The thing is that i dont get why I get a forbidden error because i gave my application all permissions for delegate and application. I'm a bit stuck on that subject.....

Comment: Did you consent to the app, or in the Azure Portal click "Grant Permissions"?  Can you grab the access token that you acquire through your code and look at the claims in the token using https://jwtinspect.azurewebsites.net/?  What "scp" or "roles" claims do you see?

Comment: I added the roles to my questions

Comment: OK.  So is your code doing `client_credentials` flow or `code` flow?

Comment: I'm doing client_credintial I think. Using secret key and clientID.

Comment: This is weird.  Can you validate that with that token you can read the group (GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}) and then try deleting.  Can you provide the **full** error message too.  It should contain a client-request-id and timestamp.

Comment: As I wrote in Marc comment I can Delete now but I cant still get Calendar and emails through my program. Do you know that there can be an issue when doing GEt requests for Events and Mail?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

The [Delete Group](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_delete) method support both Delegated (`Authorization Code` or `Implicit` OAUTH grants) and Application (`Client Credentials` OAUTH grant) models. Both Delegated and Application flows require the `Group.ReadWrite.All` scope.

The reason you're getting a `401 Unauthorized` error is that your application hasn't received [Admin Consent](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service#3-get-administrator-consent) for the tenant you're connected too. When using `Client Credentials` there is no User to authenticate so before your application can interact with the tenant, an Admin must first explicitly authorize your application and the scopes you're requesting.

You can find a walk through at [v2 Endpoint and Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/).

Comment: Hello again marc, it's nice to see that you are active and helps people like me! One thing that solved it for me was to change from /beta to /v1.0 have any idea why this could be?

Comment: It is certainly possible there was a problem with the `/beta` endpoint. You should only ever use `/beta` for POC testing of new features. It is not a supported endpoint. Only `/v1.0` is supported for production use.

Comment: +1 for what Marc says on using v1.0.  However, that is still very strange. For group deletion, /beta and /v1.0 should be equivalent.  I'll ask the engineering team to take a quick look.